# Reading data from Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am new to Pipeline world and Google API DataFlow.

I want to read data from BigQuery with sqlQuery. When I read all database it's working OK.

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<TableRow> qData = p.apply(
     BigQueryIO.Read
         .named("Read")
         .from("test:DataSetTest.data"));
```

But when I use fromQuery I got error.

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<TableRow> qData = p.apply(
     BigQueryIO.Read
         .named("Read")
         .fromQuery("SELECT * FROM DataSetTest.data"));
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation of query "SELECT * FROM DataSetTest.data" failed. If the
>   query depends on an earlier stage of the pipeline, This validation can
>   be disabled using #withoutValidation.
>
> at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Read$Bound.dryRunQuery(BigQueryIO.java:449)
>
> at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Read$Bound.validate(BigQueryIO.java:432)
>
> at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:357)
>
> at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:267)
>
> at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:47)
>
> at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:151)
>
> at
>   Test.java.packageid.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:72)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter
>   projectId must be specified.
>
> at
>   com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:229)
>
> at
>   com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:140)
>
> at
>   com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs$Query.(Bigquery.java:1751)
>
> at
>   com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Jobs.query(Bigquery.java:1724)
>
> at
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Read$Bound.dryRunQuery(BigQueryIO.java:445)
>
> ... 6 more

What is the problem here?

UPDATE:

I set project by "options.setProject".

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    options.setProject("test");
    PCollection<TableRow> qData = p.apply(
         BigQueryIO.Read
             .named("Read")
             .fromQuery("SELECT * FROM DataSetTest.data"));
```

But now I got this message. Table is not found.

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
>   {
>     "code" : 404,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Not found: Table test:_dataflow_temporary_dataset_737099.dataflow_temporary_table_550832",
>       "reason" : "notFound"
>     } ],
>     "message" : "Not found: Table test:_dataflow_temporary_dataset_737099.dataflow_temporary_table_550832"
>   }

Answer (score 6):

All resources in Google Cloud Platform, including BigQuery tables and Dataflow jobs, are associated with a cloud project. Specifying the project is necessary when interacting with GCP resources.

The exception trace is saying that no cloud project is set for the `BigQueryIO.Read` transform: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Required parameter projectId must be specified`.

Dataflow controls the default value of the cloud project via its `PipelineOptions` API. Dataflow will default to using the project across its APIs, including `BigQueryIO`.

Normally, we recommend constructing the `PipelineOptions` from command line arguments using `PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(String)` API. In this case, you'd just pass `--project=YOUR_PROJECT` on the command line.

Alternatively, this can be set manually in the code, as follows:

```
GcpOptions gcpOptions = options.as(GcpOptions.class);
options.setProject("YOUR_PROJECT");
```

Finally, starting with the version 1.4.0 of the Dataflow SDK for Java, Dataflow will default to using the cloud project set via `gcloud config set project <project>`. You can still override it via `PipelineOptions`, but don't need to. This may have worked in some scenarios even before version 1.4.0, but may not have been reliable in all scenarios or combinations of versions of Cloud SDK and Dataflow SDK.

Comment: I have specified project with Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Cloud SDK changed the location where it populates the project id. So, there's a scenario and a combination of versions of Cloud SDK and Dataflow SDK where this may not be automatically populated across the SDKs. This should be fixed with Dataflow SDK version 1.4.0 and onwards, which will be released in a few days. In the meanwhile, please specify the `--project` `PipelineOption`.

Comment: Do I need a Buckets for accessing data from GC BigQuery?

Comment: Sounds unrelated to the original question. Buckets are a concept used by Google Cloud Storage (GCS). To submit a job to the Dataflow service, you have to specify a "staging location in GCS". So, you need to have a GCS bucket for submitting any Dataflow jobs. This is completely orthogonal to BigQuery -- BigQuery doesn't have and doesn't need buckets.